# Query using reverse relationship or objects manager?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
from .models import Comment

user = request.user

comments_1 = user.comment_set.all().count()

comments_2 = Comment.objects.filter(user=user).count()
```

Between `comments_1` and `comments_2`, which one is faster? Can someone explain to me? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

I looked in Django Documentation Making queries, but does not really say about the difference in performance.

Comment: You have the code and the setup. Why are you asking us which is faster?

Comment: I assume `comments_2 = Comment.objects.filter(user=user).count() ` is faster. Because it only run on one table. Not 100% sure. Better test it.